# salt-ssh No matching sls found for 'copy.sls' in env 'base'

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to copy the files from my salt master to the minon using `salt-ssh`
with `file.managed` module. but it is giving the below error...

```
[salt]# pwd
/srv/salt
[salt]# ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  80 Sep  4 21:37 copy.sls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47 Sep  3 04:52 lftp_install.sls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44 Sep  3 04:52 lftp_remove.sls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 124 Sep  3 04:50 lftp.sls
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  65 Sep  3 04:53 Service_check.sls
[salt]# cat copy.sls
add script:
    file.managed:
    - name: testSalt
    - source: /root/testSalt
    - dest: /tmp/testSalt
```

Entries from `/etc/salt/master`

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /srv/salt
```

> [salt]# salt-ssh 'KK' state.apply copy.sls

```
KK:
    - No matching sls found for 'copy.sls' in env 'base'


When i ran this into the debug mode, it gives as follows..

[DEBUG   ] Could not find file from saltenv 'base', 'salt://copy/sls.sls'
[DEBUG   ] Could not find file from saltenv 'base', 'salt://copy/sls/init.sls'
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
KK:
    - No matching sls found for 'copy.sls' in env 'base'
```

Comment: Always use a yaml lint checker to verify there is no mix of tab and spaces on indentation. Saltstack doesn't always show correct exception error when it encounter incorrect yaml syntax.

Comment: I checked that, i dont see any indentation or tab space!

Comment: Hey, where is your top.sls?

Comment: @mootmoot,  i don't have top.sls. but i got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that, if i'll put the file to copied into the same Directory where copy.sls exits ie in my case `/srv/salt` then it works.

```
# cat copy.sls
add script:
    file.managed:
    - name: /opt/testSalt
    - source: salt://testSalt
    - user: root
    - mode: 644
```

> ## salt-ssh '*' state.sls copy

```
KK:
----------
          ID: add script
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /opt/testSalt
      Result: True
     Comment: File /opt/testSalt updated
     Started: 07:19:44.332582
    Duration: 20.366 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              diff:
                  ---
                  +++
                  @@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
                   salt copy test
                  +second commit

Summary
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
```